# how to override nb-theme font family?

Tags: angular, sass, fonts, nebular, ngx-admin

I want to apply two different font-family to my app, each for a different language.
I have both fonts files in my assets folder and have used @font-face to define them as you see here

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "myArabicFont";
  src: url("/assets/skins/fonts/arabic-ge-ss-text-light/ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myCalibri";
  src: url("/assets/skins/fonts/calibri/Exo-Regular.otf");
}
```

The problem is whether i add this line `font-family-primary: unquote("myArabicFont"),` to my `theme.scss` or not i still wanna override the font-family in the theme when app language changes

I am able to add a class on `<ngx-app/>` to take in the other font-family value, but that has no effect.

Same thing applies to the specific class added to elements when language changes, what happens then is that the font-family property value (different from the theme's) gets applied to the first element in the page and the rest ignores it and defaults to the theme's

Comment: Isn't this answers your question, https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/2059#issuecomment-632408128

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa  not exactly no. I don't want to remove the theme configurations from my app, i only wanna override the font-family when i want to

Comment: isn't it explained how to do it in the latter part of that comment in Github?

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa I want to change the whole app's font family based on language change button. that comment doesn't solve my problem